# Why the blog posts is not showing?

Tags: posts, blog, blog-page

I have created a template page called blog. now i have made blog query. but the blog posts is not showing in output. what can be the problem is? the code is below:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header();   ?>

   <div class="blog-post">

<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while(have_posts())  : the_post(); ?>
    <h2> <?php  the_title();   ?>  </h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
     <?php get_template_part('404') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>


   <!-- Start Sidebar Widgets -->
   <div class="five columns sidebar bottom-3">

     <!-- Search Widget -->
     <div class="widget search">
       <h3 class="title bottom-1">Search</h3><!-- Title Widget -->
       <?php get_search_form( ); ?>
     </div>
     <!-- End -->

     <!-- Categories Widget -->
     <div class="widget categories">

     <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>   

     <?php  endif; ?>


     </div>
     <!-- End -->

     <div class="widget categories">

     <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>   

     <?php  endif; ?>


     </div>
     <!-- End -->

     <!-- Most Posts -->

     <!-- End -->

   </div><!-- End Sidebar Widgets -->

   <div class="clearfix"></div>

   </div><!-- <<< End Container >>> -->


   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: A few questions: What version of WP? Did you copy and rename index.php? What is the file name (tpl_blog.php / etc)? Where is said file located in theme folders?

Answer (score 0):

i have got my answer. it should be query like

```
<?php query_posts ('post_type=post&post_status = publish&posts_per_page10&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
```